# Can I have fluid width on icon set using :after

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got a navigation where I've got icons after my text set using :after in the CSS:

```
a.pro-serv:after { 
  content: url('../imgs/pro.png'); 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 65px; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -31px; 
}
```

Using absolute positioning I set it so it sits under the text... (yes they are big buttons). But it's a responsive site so as the nav items shrink in width, one or two of the icons are too wide, but due to how I'm setting them I can't work out a way to change their size, and I fear I can't, but I'm hoping someone might have a solution so that for the changing size the icons react.. Is this even possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using media queries to load a smaller version of the icons? Getting background images to go responsive is a difficult task. If you put them into img tags you will have a much easier go of it